# Access HttpContext in C# Class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working on an MVC application. I have created a class to read Media Directories. I need to user `HttpContext` in this class, but i am always getting `HttpContext.Current.User` and `HttpContext.Current.Server` as `null`. Below is the code

```
public static async Task<string> GetImagesPath()
{
    return await Task.Factory.StartNew<string>(() =>
    {
        var CustomerNumber = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetCustomerNumber().Result;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CustomerNumber))
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(string.Format("~/Media/{0}/UserImages/", CustomerNumber));
        }
        return string.Empty;
    });
}
```

if there is any better way of doing the same that would be a great a help.

Comment: you can pass context to `GetImagesPath()` from the web page that will call this method

Comment: try this in controller: System.Web.HttpContext.Current

Comment: I think it is only available on the main thread. So you would need to pass it as an objectState parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current `HttpContext` depends on the current thread; since your code is running in another thread, it doesn't have access to the current `HttpContext`. Just save the context to a local variable before you run the task, and use that variable in the task:

```
public static async Task<string> GetImagesPath()
{
    var context = HttpContext.Current;
    return await Task.Factory.StartNew<string>(() =>
    {
        var CustomerNumber = context.User.Identity.GetCustomerNumber().Result;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CustomerNumber))
        {
            return context.Server.MapPath(string.Format("~/Media/{0}/UserImages/", CustomerNumber));
        }
        return string.Empty;
    });
}
```

Comment: getting the same output a `null`

Comment: @thomas I guess the issue is the `GetImagesPath` is not in a Class derived from Page class its in a different class.

Comment: yes `public class MediaDirectories` its a simple C# class

Comment: @user3389203 can you tell us at which event you are calling this `GetImagesPath` method

Comment: i am calling this from controller action method `public async Task<ActionResult> CreateUser`

Comment: this is resolved. I need to pass the `HttpContext` from main thread...correct??

Comment: Passing `HttpContext` to another thread is a **bad idea™**. It is not safe. **Do not do this.**

Comment: @Tragedian ya sure i removed that. Thanks.

Comment: @yogi, HttpContext.Current is static, so it doesn't matter which class you call it from

Answer (score 3):

`HttpContext` is only available to the request thread. Do not pass it to another thread; `HttpContext` is not threadsafe.

Instead, remove the call to `Task.Factory.StartNew`. On ASP.NET, there is (almost) never a good reason to call `Task.Run` or any other method to execute code on a thread pool thread.

```
public static string GetImagesPath()
{
    var CustomerNumber = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetCustomerNumber().Result;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CustomerNumber))
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(string.Format("~/Media/{0}/UserImages/", CustomerNumber));
    }
    return string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Then what is the best way to flush the response and not waiting for the operation to complete?

Comment: @BhushanFirake: I have no idea.